# It's nice to be picked up

Tags: riddle, word

> Open me to deal with me later;
>   Lean on me to move ahead;
>   Keep me to stay in the know;
>   Read me to choose which to pick;
>   Close me when you want to see no more.

What am I?

**Hint 1:**

> Pairing each of the five verbs with the intended answer (or a variation of it) will hopefully create a concrete action or phrase.

**Hint 2:**

> The internet, as noted in one of the guesses below, is loosely relevant to one of the lines. So is guitar-playing to another of the lines. I'll leave the other three as mysteries for now.

Comment: Cracking open a cold one (by pulling me) might have helped you solve this one!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you a

> Tab

Open me to deal with me later

> Opening a tab allows the bill to accumulate to be settled later
> It's also nice if someone picks up a group's tab.

Lean on me to move ahead

> Pressing the Tab key makes a large space in text

Keep me to stay in the know

> You keep tabs on something to keep informed about it

Read me to choose which to pick

> Reading a tab shows which fret on which string to play on a guitar.
> I originally thought this may have been a TAB form (racing guide) but figured it was too localised.

Close me when you want to see no more

> Closing a tab in an internet browser

Comment: Whoa, a perfect answer! That's correct, and I couldn't have explained the clues better myself.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like a

> **Newspaper** or an online **newsfeed**

*Open me to deal with me later;*

> People who *buy* newspapers seldom read it the first time they open it. A lot of people first bookmark newsfeed to read them later.

*Lean on me to move ahead;*

> Lean towards the paper or screen to read.

*Keep me to stay in the know;*

> To know the news

*Read me to choose which to pick;*

> You can pick the topic on the newspaper only by reading the headings

*Close me when you want to see no more.*

> Close it once you’re done reading.

Comment: Still not quite my intended answer. I'm mostly sold on all of your interpretations except the second line, which falls apart. I mean some sort of concrete interpretation of "lean on" and/or "move ahead"...

Comment: I will also add that "deal with me later" in the first line is no ambiguity, it's truly the reason to "open me"!

Comment: @anodyne Added the edits so it doesn’t seem far off. But I’ll continue thinking to see this riddle through.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I have a complete answer. But, are you

> an ear

Open me to deal with me later

> Keeping your ears open is to stay informed. I'm not sure if this fits.

Lean on me to move ahead

> Leaning on an ear would move a head

Keep me to stay in the know

> Keeping your ears open or to the ground is to stay informed

Read me to choose which to pick;

> Ear reading is listening to audio books. Not sure how this relates exactly.

Close me when you want to see no more.

> Closing your ears is to ignore something, i.e. act blindly

It's nice to be picked up

> It can be enjoyable to pick and clean an ear

Comment: Interesting but not quite. The intended answer is tighter on all fronts, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Are you an

> **Internet ?**

Open me to deal with me later;

> You first need to turn on the internet before surfing the web

Lean on me to move ahead;

> Once the internet connection is enstablished, you can continue with your
>  works or surfs

Keep me to stay in the know;

> You need to have the internet to stay updated

Read me to choose which to pick;

> You can choose which article or website to read further

Close me when you want to see no more.

> Close browsers when you are done perhaps?

Comment: Closer but not quite the intended answer. Your last clue interpretation happens to be, however, extremely close. I'll add a general hint in response to the rest.

Comment: aww I was about to edit to "browser" but the answer is published. nice riddle btw :)