# I'm a Pick-up Artist

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

Before the ladies I arrive
Perhaps, with 4 wheel drive
The greatest of my charms
Lies in my two arms -
I say half my name, split
But I'm not too full of it:
I may not be the smartest,
But I'm a pick-up artist

What am I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you a:

> Forklift?

Before the ladies I arrive

> This could be a play on the word "dolly", which is a lightweight way to lift and move heavy objects and could be construed as a (somewhat sexist) slang term for a lady?

Perhaps, with 4 wheel drive

> Some forklifts are 4wd

The greatest of my charms
Lies in my two arms -

> The two arms (or forks) of a forklift are pretty much it's reason for being

I say half my name, split

> The name "forklift" can be split into two halves - fork and lift - which describe what the machine does

But I'm not too full of it:

> A humble, working-mans machine :)

I may not be the smartest,
But I'm a pick-up artist

> They're not the most complicated of machines, but really good at picking things up - and putting things down. (Now I have the [Crown jingle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=89TdudGzqmg) in my head)

Comment: Re "I say half my name, split": rot13(gur svefg unys - sbex - zrnaf 'fcyvg', yvxr n sbex va gur ebnq)

Comment: TIL: there are rough-terrain versions that are indeed 4WD. Never encountered one before.

Comment: This was, of course, inspired by [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94895/its-nice-to-be-picked-up)